# How to model infinite non-linear combination?

Tags: design, architecture, math, architectural-patterns, modeling

Let L be an ordered set of positive integers (for example, the set of all primes).

Here, #L = infinity, and N is a positive number serving as an upper limit. Goal is to list the following set M:

M = {all **multiplicative non-linear combinations** of L | each multiplicative combination < N}

For example, if `L = {a,b,c, ..., inf}`, a snippet of combination could be

```
{a*b   ,a*c    ,...,   a*inf}
{a^2 *b, a^2 *c,..., a^2*inf}
...
{a*b*c , a*c*d ,..., y*z*inf}
...
```

Assuming L would be finite, with #L = n, then the program would require n levels of looping,but in my problem n is unknown, instead there is the condition about N. I don't know how to **loop such an unknown number of nested levels**. It's this but which I'm struggling with - how to model an unknown number of loops, rather than an unknown threshold.

**Specific problem details**

**List**: list of primes P that is expanding.

**Constraints**: non-primes (none linear multiplicative combination of primes) under N.

Comment: What will you do with the resulting sets? Any model must first have a purpose.

Comment: as written above multiplicative non-linear combination of arbitrary set, the specific set in the problem is prime numbers, and the condition is under integer N such that N>2, that particular method above is required, and not otherwise e.g sieving.

Comment: "looping unknown looping can't be modeled programmatically, is there other way around?" Isn't that what a `while` loop is for? Looping until a specific condition is met?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. What approach/methodology do you have in mind when talking about "programmatic modeling", and why do you think this problem cannot be modeled with that approach? And what does "looping unknown looping" mean? I suggest you tell us your favorite programming language, and I am pretty sure someone here can tell you how to model the problem in this language.

Comment: @DocBrown edited now

Comment: #L is infinity or unknown?

Comment: @Goyo limited by condition that "multiplicative combination < N"

Comment: Your statement of the problem is inherently impossible to solve. No program can list all combinations of an infinite list. Unless you have a constraint on elements of the list, such as "monotonically increasing", to allow setting an upper bound, it can't be done.

Comment: @BobDalgleish constraint for multiplicative combination  under N

Comment: Just to be sure. Basically you want every combination of any number of numbers in a given set. (each pair, then each triplet, then each 4...). For very large or Unknown sets. Assuming this is right? What is your problem? Dealing with the unknownness or large size? Ensuring that every combination is covered? Or managing the 2 movements (within a section and between section. Or just the code itself?

Comment: @3C273 dealing with unknown large number, every combination must be covered, the list is the primes under N.

Comment: It seems to mw that Samuel's answer is your solution. What problem do you see with it?

Comment: in imperative terms i have to write unknown loops for/while which impossible, what lazy evaluation offers is operation on unknown list limit, or infinite size, and not unlimited number of loops recursive loops for(){for(){....}}

Comment: @Error I gave you an example of the fibonacci sequence that uses recursion. How is that not suitable for your application? You can have streams of streams as well. It can definitely model your application.

Comment: I missunderstood you then. I'll try looking into it when i'm back home. But for loops qithin loops within loops situation, I would think there is a recurive solution for it. (where each recursion is a new loop with specific parameters). You might run into memory or stack limitations but in theory it should work.

Comment: @Samuel i will check that  "lazy evaluation of unlimited looping levels"

Comment: I'm honestly having a very hard time trying to understand your question.

Comment: @T.Sar edited with problem details

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure that I understood what you are after, but what you asked for looks to me like it could be solved it this way (which requires 3 nested loops, not more):

1. start with L1={a}, generate all "multiplicative non-linear combinations" containing a (so a^2, a^3, ...) below N. Lets call these products P1, it is a finite set.
2. continue with with L2={a,b}, generate all of these combinations where b is a factor (a^2*b, a^3*b, a^4*b, ...), (a^2*b^2, a^3*b^2, ...), where no number exceeds N. You can utilize the results from step 1 and implement it like this:

   ```
    P0={1}
    Q=union of P0,P1
    for(i=1; b^i < N; ++i):
       for each p in Q:
          if b^i*p > N: break;
          P2.insert(b^i*p);
   ```
3. now you see how this continues: lets say L3={a,b,c}, generate all combinations where c is a factor. Do this by utilizing the resultset P2:

   ```
    Q=union of P0,P1,P2
    for(i=1; c^i < N; ++i):
       for each p in Q:
          if c^i*p > N: break;
          P3.insert(c^i*p);
   ```

Repeat this until the last element in step k, the last element of L_k exceeds N (actually N/2 should be enough).

Finally, merge the results P1, P2, ..., P_k into a single resultset.

Comment: the element {a, b, c, ...} are of unknown limit, bounded by condition, which requires unknown # of for loops!

Comment: @Error: you said one knows N, and L is the set of all primes. So one only needs to loop over all elements of L from 2 to the maximum prime below N/2. This looks like a known limit to me. But independently from this, the solution in my answer requires simply **3** nested loops, not more. If that is not what you are after, please invest more time into your problem description to make it clearer (start with writing in full sentences, using punctuation and correct lower/upper case letters).

Comment: it's pruned now

Comment: @Error: sorry, but from your mumble I have a hard time to understand what you mean. Either I did not understand your problem description, or you did not understand my solution. So try to give a better description, or tell me exactly why you think this is not a solution.

Comment: while ignoring loop of expansion(prime list), first loop for primes iteration, second for prime power iteration, third for multiplicative combination with the old generated array in your case Pi, that would work, but in your code , first loop for prime iteration, second for prime power iteration, and **the third** for multiplicative combination with only the first generated array P1, it should be P2, and so on, and no merging at the end.

Comment: @Error: ok, that is a comment I understood, and you are right, I missed that. But it is easy to fix, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Many languages support infinite series with [lazy evaluated streams](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011fa/supplemental/lec24-streams/streams.htm). You can operate on streams without actually evaluating any elements in the stream. [Here](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_14.html) is a Scala example for the Fibonacci sequence.

Here's a Scala example that yields combinations

```
val L = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray.toList.map(_.toString).toStream
def combinations(stream: Stream[String], i: Int): Stream[Stream[String]] =
    stream.combinations(i).toStream.map(comb => 
        comb.reduceLeft((a, b) => s"$a*$b")) #:: combinations(stream, i + 1)
val N = 4
val result = combinations(L.take(N), 1).take(N)
result.toList.foreach(s => println(s.toList))
```

Yields

```
List(a, b, c, d)
List(a*b, a*c, a*d, b*c, b*d, c*d)
List(a*b*c, a*b*d, a*c*d, b*c*d)
List(a*b*c*d)
```

Comment: no not that either, question edited.

Comment: see my edit for a scala program that yields combinations

Comment: i didn't wrote in the question explicitly that the combination required is repetitive, but i showed that is the case in the examples, your output is the possible non-repetitive combination, in repetitive case the output is infinite list of size infinity, but there is a constraint "multiplicative repetitive combination < N" which makes it finite.

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: my program creates a stream. it supports infinite recursion. as you can see I defined N=4 so the program would exit. otherwise the program would never terminate.

Comment: ok i will take scala tutorial in few minutes, and review your answer, as i never been experienced  with lazy evaluation programming.

Comment: I was midway of hacking a c# solution similar to this, but yours work nicely. Popped an upvote to ya!

Comment: your script critique with simpler example, for L  = "abc", combinations would be { {{a}, {b}, {c}}, {{a,b}, {a,c}, {b,c}}, {{a,b,c}} } which would produce result { {a, b, c}, {ab, ac, bc}, {abc}}, and what is missing is { {a^2, a^3, ..., a^inf}, {a^2 *b, a^3 *b, ..., a^inf *b }, {a^2 *b^2, a^3 * b^2, ..., a^inf *b^2}, etc.

Comment: my example was to show combinations are possible. I wasn't trying to give you the code. it's up to you to produce a program that produces the exact results you need